# Crontab with script to notify-send

Tags: bash, cron, notification

I'm trying to set up a **bash script** which is send a gui notification when a file is created in a folder.
Everything works when I launch it in terminal, but when I set up at boot with **crontab**, the script is running but the notification doesn't show on gui.
I tried differents options than I saw on askubuntu like explicit the display, but nothing works.

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0.0 && /my/script.sh >> /my/script.log
```

Thanks for the help ..

Comment: If you want the `DISPLAY` variable to be available in the environment of the `/my/script.sh` command, omit the `&&` (or explicitly `export` it). The value should probably be `:0` rather than `:0.0`

Comment: Oh sorry, I explicitly exported it, and I will try with :0 but I think I already did it.

Comment: You may want to add the the line `my/script.sh >> /my/script.log` as an entry in the **Startup Applications** app. That way the script will be activated **after** you login and not at reboot.

Comment: Yes that's the best way I think, thank you so much ! I totally forgot about this possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `notify-send` to work in a cron job you have to copy the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` from your current desktop session and set it in the cron job. Also, `notify-send` must run as the same user who is currently logged in to the desktop session. You don't need the `DISPLAY` variable.

At least that works for me.

However, this will not work `@reboot`, because at that time there is no desktop session to which `notify-send` can send notifications. To see notifications, you must run it at some later time, when desktop session already exists.

Comment: How can I set the env variable in the cron job ? And how can I tell to Cron than wait the session to start the script ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @rhadamanthe Do you really need to run your script from cron, and at reboot?
Maybe you can just add the script to startup applications of your desktop session? In that case it will start when session starts, and you don't need to set any environment variables because they're already set properly.

Comment: Didn't realize that I could do this way ! When I searched for launch script at start up I found crontab and I just continue without think about others ways ! Thank you so much